# Update SQL inner Join success but update all list

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have two table (katalan and dominus) with relation in code_id , when I use select

```
select No_list, name, a.code_id, b.address, email
from katalan a inner join dominus b on a.code_id=b.code_id
where b.address='NY'
order by No_list;
```

show like below:

```
No_list name    a.code_id   b.address   email
1       ahmed   222           NY        cccc@bcde.com
2       hasan   222           NY        bbbb@bcde.com
3       david   222           NY        aaaa@bcde.com
```

In my case, I want update b.address specifically only if

```
No_list='1'
```

this my query,

```
UPDATE b 
set b.address='LA' 
from dbo.katalan as a 
inner join dbo.dominus as b 
on a.code_id=b.code_id
where a.No_list='1';
```

but when I've updated, show like below

```
No_list name    a.code_id   b.address   email
1       ahmed   222           LA        cccc@bcde.com
2       hasan   222           LA        bbbb@bcde.com
3       david   222           LA        aaaa@bcde.com
```

My condition table in dominus when select

```
select * from dominus where code_id='222'
```

My table show like below after update, before update address must be 'NY':

```
code_id    address  
 222          LA
```

Expectation when I'm doing update just 1 list updated like below:

```
No_list name    a.code_id   b.address   email
1       ahmed   222           LA        cccc@bcde.com
2       hasan   222           NY        bbbb@bcde.com
3       david   222           NY        aaaa@bcde.com
```

Note:
I made simple explanation for my problem with this condition.

In this condition I just want update address just 1 list with No_list = 1. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your update query syntax is wrong. You cannot use `from` in the update query. Basic gist of Update query syntax in MySQL: `Update <tables with joins> Set <field = value> Where <conditions>`

Full syntax and description, can be read at [MySQL doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html):

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET assignment_list
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]

value:
    {expr | DEFAULT}

assignment:
    col_name = value

assignment_list:
    assignment [, assignment] ...
```

Try the following instead:

```
UPDATE dbo.katalan AS a 
INNER JOIN dbo.dominus AS b ON a.code_id = b.code_id
SET b.address = 'LA' 
WHERE a.No_list = '1';
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it seem I wrong to know relation id in my table. I will answer my question self.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solve when I add additional value in code_id in dominus table, so when I select

```
select * from dominus;
```

show record like below:

```
code_id    address  
 221          LA
 222          NY
```

And simple query update

```
update katalan
set code_id ='221'
where No_list='1';
```

work like a charm

```
No_list name    a.code_id   b.address   email
1       ahmed   221           LA        cccc@bcde.com
2       hasan   222           NY        bbbb@bcde.com
3       david   222           NY        aaaa@bcde.com
```